# How to color the syntax of my own language - textarea

Tags: javascript, css, html

I've searched but didn't find any answer :( I am searching for a plugin or a library or something to activate syntax coloration of my own language in a textarea (HTML). 
Just coloring some key-words, numbers, strings, etc.

Can you help me please ?

(Sorry if my english is bad.)

Comment: You can't do this in textarea, for instance code mirror is using content editable or design mode, don't know which one.

Comment: You can leverage ace editor and build your own syntax highlighter using it's framework. https://ace.c9.io/#nav=about

Comment: I downloaded Ace, Perfect !!! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

try with this
[Make a syntax highlighter for MySQL using JavaScript and Regex](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/mysql-syntax-highlighter-javascript-regex)

just change the keywords